# Optimizing code to populate a new column in a huge table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm about to add a new column to a table with 37M rows. The column will hold an association ID.

Simple model:

```rb
class SeenEpisode < ActiveRecord::Base
  #show_id is the new column
  attr_accessible :user_id, :season_id, :episode_id, :show_id
  belongs_to :episode
  belongs_to :season
end
```

This is the fastest way that I can come up with:

```
seen_episodes = SeenEpisode.where("show_id IS NULL")
seen_episodes.find_in_batches do |batch| #batch size is 1000
  batch.group_by(&:season_id).each do |season_id, seen_episodes|
    #all seen_episodes with the same season_id, ensures the same show_id
    show_id = seen_episodes.first.episode.show_id
    seen_episodes.each do |seen_episode|
      seen_episode.update_column(:show_id, show_id) #skip validations and callbacks
    end
  end
end
```

Current tests on development shows that populating 10.000 records take about 2 minutes.
Lets say it will take 1 minute on production, due to better hardware and mysql configs, it will still take 100 minutes per million records. That's like 60 hours.

Is there any chance that there is a faster way going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you batch writes, it will be order of magnitudes faster. I mean, instead of sending individual writes

```
update episodes set show_id = 1 where episode_id = 1;
update episodes set show_id = 1 where episode_id = 2;
update episodes set show_id = 1 where episode_id = 3;
```

You should group them into a single write

```
update episodes set show_id = 1 where episode_id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Or, something like this could work:

```
select season_id, show_id 
from episodes 
where show_id is not null 
group by season_id;
```

That should fetch one `show_id` for each `season_id`. Then just loop over those rows and fire mass updates (SQL syntax for simplicity, you'll likely do this in ruby)

```
update episodes set show_id = @show_id where season_id = @season_id;
```

Comment: I went with your first suggestion. With a batch_size of 100000, I'm now down to about 30 seconds per 100000 records, meaning around 3 hours (from 60), and that's on my slow development machine :) Thanks alot!